# How to Refer to a Subview Button of Custom UIView in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I'm facing problems with UITableViewCell being reused, and I am receiving suggestions to make the action of a UIButton occur within the UITableViewController.
The problem is that because the UIButton is instantiated within the custom UIView subclass, I cannot find a way to refer to it.

The code is:

```
class StarButton: UIView {

var buttonRow : Int = 0
var buttonSelected : Bool = false

override init (frame : CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame : frame)
    initStar()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initStar()
}

func initStar(){

    let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
    let emptyStarImage = UIImage(named: "emptyStar")

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 33, height: 33))

    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StarButton.fillingStar(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)

    if buttonSelected == true{
        button.selected = true
    }

    addSubview(button)
}

//Could have various errors
func fillingStar(sender: UIButton){
    if (sender.selected) == false{
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.setObject(ChemQuizCollection.wordListObject.quizList[buttonRow], forKey: "\(buttonRow)")
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.synchronize()
    } else{
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.removeObjectForKey("\(buttonRow)")
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        FavoritesManager.favoritesList.synchronize()
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    for view in subviews
    {
        view.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}

override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

}

This is the custom UIView subclass. I want to refer to the "button" in func initStar().
Using
    for subview in instantiatedStarButton.subviews{
        subview.selected = true
    }
throws an error saying UIView doesn't have member "selected". Is there a better way?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your code

```
StarButton.subviews{ subview.selected = true }
```

`.subviews` give `UIView` not `UIButton`: `UIView` has no `.selected` property

What should be done is following code or something similar. You have to cast tour `UIView` to `UIButton`

```
let filtured  =  instantiatedStarButton.subviews.filter({
            if let button = $0 as? UIButton{
                return button.selected
            }
            return false
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really helped :). What does $0 mean?

Comment: Every single element in array , that is what $0 means. 

Please check Documents for if let 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: Ah thanks for the quick reply to the question :). I just looked up $0 to figure out its meaning and realized you already responded! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

buttonSelected is set to false while you are only changing the state of the button if its true. That's why you're getting the error.

You can either change the buttonSelected to true, or even better assign a tag to the button and compare that tag with the 'sender' in fillingStar.

Comment: buttonSelected is set to false as a default value. It doesn't affect nor does it explain why .selected is not a member of subview of my StarButton.